# Can't get alert or confirms to work in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: thanks to all of you it has been fixed (: thank you soooooooo much

I cant get the alert,confirm or prompt to work, here is my code (not the full code but the beginning is the part tht I cant get to work so im leaving that and omitting the end of the code, so here it is :

```js
var warGood = 0
    var warEvil = 0
    var life

    var mh = false

    var document.Gold = 1000;
    var gems = 1000;
    var lb = false
    var Stellar_grenades  = 0
    var Cosmic_grenades = 0;
    var Level = 1    
    var person
    
    person = prompt("please enter your name", "Specimen")

    if (person != null) {
      if (person == "shit") {
        alert("Really? choose a new MORE APPROPRIATE name", "Ok ill choose a new More APPROPRIATE name")
      }

    else if (person != "shit"){
      if (person != null) {alert(
        "welcome "  + person + " to the universe")
      }
    }

    alert(
    "not too long ago your planet was blown up in the midst of a universal war, you luckily survived and fled to another planet");
    alert("You are now here, On Planet Vecron, Here you will build up your    base,")
    alert("then you can eventually go on missions to distant planets,")
    alert("Upon Reaching the final mission, you will notice one thing")
    alert ("Your Not on a new planet, but rather a new universe,")
    alert("this universe holds the Key to cosmic peace,")
    alert(" This Key is the Community Pendant")
    
    life = confirm("Do you have what it takes to get this pendant and end the universal war?")
    
     if (life == true) { 
      alert("Thank you " + person + "You will make a fine adventurer");
      alert("gold is the main currency Here on vecron")
      alert(" If you want anything it can buy it, with a few exceptions")
      alert("You cant buy the Community Pendant")
      alert(" Or gems Or the special 12 summoners tools")
      alert(" Shh the summoners tools will be talked about later")
      alert("saving your game is important,")
      alert("To Open the shop Press S")
      alert("To Save Press F")
      alert("To get money you simply have to press the money button!")
      alert("The Ding Is to make sure you actually have good reflexes while in missions.")
      alert("You get missions after you unlock the mission hall")
      alert("then you can start the first journey on your many adventures")
      document.write("you have " + document.Gold + " Gold and " + gems + " gems")
      alert("Go Get that Pendant and save the world")
```

```html
<img src = "logo.png" alt = "logo">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I really cant figure it out, it was working fine a few weeks ago, then I took a break and came back to it and all of a sudden it wouldn't work anymore

Comment: `var document.Gold = 1000;` isn’t valid JavaScript. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: Learn to use your developer console. I am sure it has errors in the console.

Comment: You're missing the end brace after your `if(person != null)` statement and before the `else if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document.gold isn't valid JS. If you want global variables you can just use the `var` keyword. This will add them to the global scope. Like this:

```
var gold = 1000;
```

Document the main object of the `DOM` API. The HTML document is parsed and loaded into memory in a JS representation. You then can modify the DOM which will cause the UI to update. You are already doing this in the following code (changed it a bit):

```js
var gold = 1000;
var gems = 25;

document.write("you have " + gold + " Gold and " + gems + " gems")
```

Comment: I tried this however when I later called the variable in a button script it wouldn't work which is why I tried using it but ill change it back, thank u, I just read somewhere that you could add an object to the document which could be used similarly to a global variable...